# Safari 5.1 is pushing margins/padding out more than 50+ pixels

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

I can't figure this out (after much trying) and can't seem to find any answers on the web. I've adjusted margins, padding and borders. None will budge Safari 5.1. I've got a 35 px right-padding inserted here on the home page (see attachment). Looks fine on other browsers, but Safari pushes the padding out by over 50 pixels. Any ideas how to fix, hack or re-work? URL is hazelhomemaker.com I'm using WordPress with a child theme.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the link to your page? or just post your code here. You may knew this if you use [word-wrap](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap) it can be corrected.

Comment: Link is in the original post: hazelhomemaker.com. Word wrap didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned specifying margins/padding/borders, but did you set a `max-width` for that div?  That should keep the text from going past where you want it to stop in any/most browsers.

Comment: Nope. No luck. Worked in all browsers EXCEPT Safari 5.1. I have tried endless things but I'm still very much perplexed.

Answer (score 0):

When I analyzed your code I understood that it is not content (text), but it is a **transparent image**. So obviously `word-wrap` would be failed here.

The problem is that you are not using separate class for this `img` tag (You are giving the same properties to a bundle of tags in your page). So assign a separate class to `img` tag and give the below properties. Your problem will be solved.

```
width:90%; /* Give width only in percentages */
margin:0 auto;
```

If `margin:0 auto` doesn't work then give `text-align:center` to your `div.block-content`.

Comment: I changed it from text to an image because I didn't get a solution that worked. It was originally text when I posted this question.

Comment: @Deanna Then for `image` the above solution should work I think. Have you tried it? If it doesnt then change it into text so that I can look for a solution :)